# auto_ptr not working as expected - Compile error

Tags: c++, qnx, auto-ptr

---

**MASSIVE EDIT:**

Following juanchopanza advice, I managed to get this minimal example:

```
#include <memory>

struct a{
    int b;
};

int main()
{

    typedef std::auto_ptr<a> ArgAutoPtr;

    ArgAutoPtr floatingArg;

    floatingArg = ArgAutoPtr( new a );

}
```

Which gives me the error:

```
no match for 'operator=' in 'm_floatingArg = std::auto_ptr<a>(((a*)operator new(4u)))'
```

QNX 6.4.1 with GCC 4.3.3

**EDIT**

I managed to compile it like this. Does this work as expected or will generate... whatever evil `auto_ptr` generates?

```
ArgAutoPtr floatingArg2 = ArgAutoPtr( new a );
floatingArg = floatingArg2;
```

Comment: @drescherjm `auto_ptr` is the oldest smart pointer in C++ - so old it's been deprecated.

Comment: `auto_ptr` was a failed experiment.  Are you absolutely sure you want to use it?

Comment: @drescherjm It does have support, we have code that uses it (not that I'm happy about that...)

Comment: Sorry. I misread totally. I saw std::auto_ptr thought about std::shared_ptr.

Comment: @Yakk I'd rather not use it, but this is open source code (which was not written by me), and the `auto_ptr` part is for the special cases (like mine) that don't support `unique_ptr`. I'm just wondering if someone has ever had this problem before =)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you posted a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Most of the code you posted looks like noise.

Comment: That cannot be the entire error message.  I'm not even seeing the TYPE of the left hand side of the expression there.  Is there really no more to the errors you are getting?

Comment: @juanchopanza got it, hope it helps! =)

Comment: @Yakk You could see the type, but it doesn't matter anymore, I rearranged my question =)

Comment: Strangely enough it works when I test it, I wonder if GCC has an extension to allow this? http://ideone.com/NHJdPJ

Comment: @MarkRansom I believe it's my particular platform what's giving me trouble.

Comment: ... of course there is `m_floatingArg.reset(new a)`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `ArgAutoPtr( new a )` is creating a temporary `auto_ptr`.

`auto_ptr::operator=` takes a *non-const* reference to its argument, unlike every other example of `operator=`. A non-const reference cannot be bound to a temporary.

Comment: So... is this impossible as it is?

Comment: @ArthurChamz just create a new variable instead of using a temporary.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `auto_ptr` quirks... would something like the example I post in my new edit work?

Comment: @ArthurChamz your example should work fine, but I wouldn't use `m_` for a variable that's not a member of a class. There's another answer just posted that has a more direct way of doing it too.

Comment: Thanks, it is a member variable in my original context, but I carried it along for the example. I'll make good use of both suggestions, and read more about `auto_ptr`, thanks again for all your help =)

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the variable of type `auto_ptr<T>`, it's easier to supply the new pointer directly into its `reset` method. For example, your case would become this:

```
std::auto_ptr<a> myptr;
// : : :
myptr.reset(new a);
```

If you're constructing a fresh `auto_ptr<T>`, you can call its constructor directly to be clear on what you're doing:

```
std::auto_ptr<a> myptr2(new a);
```

(As an side note obsoleted by later edits, naming a local with prefix `m_` is likely to mislead most readers of that code.)

Comment: Thanks for the `m_` tip. In my original context it is a member variable, but I carried along the name when I was setting up my example.